# Exiting current scope

Tags: tensorflow

I have some function that I repeatedly call to generate summaries. It really clutters the graph and it makes debugging it really hard.

Is there a way to exit the scope for the particular function?
Like creating a with block that goes to the root.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`with tf.name_scope(None):`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#name_scope) to define a block of operations that will be created in the root scope.

(Note that this functionality is not documented as part of [`tf.name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/utility_functions#name_scope), but it is documented in [`tf.Graph.name_scope()`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/framework/core_graph_data_structures#Graph.name_scope), which `tf.name_scope()` wraps.)